# How to move/rename user mbox file with mailutils?

Tags: email, mail-command

Is there a way to change the `~/mbox` file where `mailutils`'s `mail` program saves read mail and where `mail -f` reads from to something else, like `~/.mbox` for example? I read that setting the `MBOX` environment variable does this but I tried setting it to both `~/.mbox` and `$HOME/.mbox` and neither did anything for me. For reference, I tried setting `MBOX` both just by setting it in the current terminal session and by using the `env` command, and neither worked.

Comment: Please provide more detail on the situation, such as how/where you set the env variable MBOX. These may help though
https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/mail_location/
https://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox

Comment: @Joe There, added some more info. I'm not sure if those links are relevant though since they're for Dovecot and I'm using mailutils, unless they're compatible or something?

Comment: ~/.mailrc is the configuration file you should be altering not ~/.mbox

Comment: https://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#Mail-Configuration-Files

Comment: @Joe I wasn't trying to edit ~/.mbox, that's what I wanted to rename my user mailbox file to so it wouldn't be visible all the time, and I wanted to know if there were any config options that would let me do that.

Comment: Yes you would have to change you mbox folder to ~/.mbox in your configuration files mentioned above

Comment: @Joe Yes but that's what I'm asking how to do. I tried looking over the mailutils docs, Google, and here on SE and I couldn't find anything that said how to do this. Maybe I just missed it but that's why I'm asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

In mailutils 3.14 the MBOX environment variable seems to work:

```
export MBOX=.fubar
```

will coax mail into saving your messages in `~/.fubar`.
Note: no directory specified here.

I keep a statement like this in my `.profile` so it is the login environment.